# Android - Image picker doesn't work on Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, mediastore, kindle-fire

I have the following code to display an imagepicker.
After user picks an image onActivityResult gets called, to return me the data for the selected image.

On kindle however, I get a resultCode of 0, and data as null.
Anyone else has noticed this problem before?
This problem happens only on kindle fire.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: We just started getting complaints about this yesterday as well....was there perhaps an update to the Kindle Gallery app recently? I experience identical symptoms as you do. Right now we are telling our customers to install ES File Mangager, neé Astro File Manager, which works fine on Kindle Fire for picking images.

Comment: Downloaded a couple of photo editing apps from Amazon Market, and non of them can pull images from Galary. So I guess this really is a bug in kindle fire

Comment: The bundled contacts app cannot pull images from Gallery either.

Comment: I pinged Amazon on this and they responded that they are aware of the issue and are working to resolve it.

Comment: @roundhill Can you please share their response about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into this exact same issue. Prior to the recent Kindle Fire update, which happened a few days ago for me, picking images from the gallery worked fine for me.
So the most recent Kindle Fire update must have introduced this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data back from such calls in two ways:  either in the actual intent data, or in Intent.EXTRA_STREAM.  If you get something back in EXTRA_STREAM it will be a mediastore content:// URL which you'd use a Cursor to look up.

Comment: the Intent comes back as null